# Issues Installing PHP on IIS 6

Tags: php, iis, iis-6

I know this is going to be a long shot... but I am following this tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/50455/how-to-install-php-on-iis-6-for-windows-server-2003/

I followed the instructions pretty much to a T, except that the downloaded non thread safe folder did not contain a PEAR directory. I downloaded PHP 5.4.26 - do I still need PEAR?

I created a page to get the phpinfo and I get Page cannot be found.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are getting a 404 this suggests its not an integration problem with PHP but just an IIS problem. Not what your going to be looking for but you should seriously consider a more up-to-date environment than 2003 and iis 6, a world of hurt awaits you due to its age.

Comment: I made a change and now get the following error: You have attempted to execute a CGI, ISAPI, or other executable program from a directory that does not allow programs to be executed. -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Any thoughts? @NeilMasters

Comment: did you give execute permission to the app pool user on the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the Web Platform installer at www.microsoft.com/web to install PHP Manager and PHP ... that's an automated install and will take care of pretty much everything ...

Answer (score 0):

Works now after setting Execute Permissions to Scripts only for my site.